# How to manage Angular element update on the list

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I'm working on a carApplication which provides to select a car and add some modifications on it.In this app I have two models extended to my tuning Parts and Order arrays.On the Tuning tab of the application,there's a table which shows name of the parts and their prices(its like menu).And on the right side there's a card element which shows what user ordered to user(Like a cart).I designed everything and works pretty well except one problem.And that problem is when I manage the amount of already ordered parts on the cart(When user order twice or more any part on the list,it doesn't just update on the card element,it also updates on the menu also and I don't want it.In the picture spoiler's price is 2500$ but when user adds to cart it's being updated also as new value on the menu.Im completely working on different arrays so I didn't understand why that parts array being uptaded.Here's what I tried below with pictures also

https://ibb.co/xHrVh3N

https://ibb.co/LYkQkPj

**HTML**

```
  <div class="row no-gutters" style="margin-top:30px">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
            <table class="table table-sm">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Parts</th>
                <th scope="col">Price</th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr *ngFor="let i of parts;let a = index">
                <td>{{i.name}}</td>
                <td>{{i.price}}$</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-alert" (click)="onAddItem(i)" >Add To Cart</button></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
               <mat-card>
                <label for="Your Cart" style="font-size: 1.875em;">Your Cart</label>
                <hr>
                <table class="table" *ngIf="orders.length>0">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Part</th>
                            <th scope="col">Amount</th>
                            <th scope="col">Price</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr *ngFor="let order of orders;">
                            <td>{{order.name}}</td>
                            <td>{{order.amount}}</td>
                            <td>{{order.price}}</td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <hr>
                        <strong>Total Cost: {{totalCost}}</strong>
                      </table>
               </mat-card>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**Component.ts**

```
export class CarTuningComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { } 
  private parts:Tuning[]=[
     new Tuning(1,'Front Bumper',3000,1),
     new Tuning(2,'Rear Bumper',2000,1),
     new Tuning(3,'Side Bumper',1000,1),
     new Tuning(4,'Body Kit',10000,1),
     new Tuning(5,'Spoiler',2500,1),
     new Tuning(6,'Exhaust',2000,1),
     new Tuning(7,'Lights',2000,1),
     new Tuning(8,'Sticker',1000,1),
     new Tuning(9,'Neon',500,1),
     new Tuning(10,'Paint',800,1),
     new Tuning(11,'Rims',1500,1),
     new Tuning(12,'Tires',2000,1),
     new Tuning(13,'Brakes',4500,1),
     new Tuning(14,'Suspension',3500,1),
     new Tuning(15,'Engine',8000,1),
     new Tuning(16,'Turbo',4000,1),
     new Tuning(17,'Transmission',3250,1)
  ];
  private orders:Order[]=[];
  totalCost:number=0;
  onAddItem(value:Tuning)
  {
    console.log(this.orders);
    console.log(this.parts);
   if(this.orders.find(i => i.name===value.name))
   {
      let myIndex= this.orders.indexOf(value);
      value.amount++;
      this.orders[myIndex].price+=this.orders[myIndex].price;
   } 
  else
   {
    this.orders.push(value);
   }   
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**Order.model.Ts**

```
export class Order{
    public name:string;
    public price:number;
    public amount:number;
    constructor(id:number,name:string,price:number,amount:number)
    {
        this.name=name;    
        this.price=price;
        this.amount=amount;
    }
}
```

**Tuning.Ts**

```
export class Tuning{
    public id:number;
    public name:string;
    public price:number;
    public amount:number;
    constructor(id:number,name:string,price:number,amount:number)
    {
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;    
        this.price=price;
        this.amount=amount;
    }
}
```

Comment: You likely have a value reference here. Please copy your objects

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm what do you mean exactly?Could you give me an example please?

Comment: The object within both arrays point to the very same object.

Comment: yeah because value comes from that parts array.What else it could be?